# ASP.NET start-up page to record user details in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I need to insert a record (username, department) in the backend SQL database table everytime a user enter a ASP.NET website (only if user is unique in the table).

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET - where is the page/function that is only run ONCE per user session in which I could enter codes to capture this detail? The user could enter the site from a number of pages.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not on a page. it is in `global.asax` as

```
void Session_OnStart() {
   // your code goes here.
}
```